# How to lock orientation for specific screen on TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I used `TabNavigation` for my app. In some screen, I want it only display on `portrait` orientation, and others are `landscape`. I've found `react-native-orientation` and try in my screens:

**Screen 1**

```
import React from "react";
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
import { Text } from 'react-native'

export default Screen1 extends React.PureComponent{

 componentDidMount(){
  Orientation.lockToLandscape();
 }

 componentWillUnmount(){
  Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
 }

 render() {
  return(<Text>Screen 1</Text>);
 }
}
```

**Screen 2**

```
import React from "react";
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
import { Text } from 'react-native'

export default Screen2 extends React.PureComponent{

 componentDidMount(){
  Orientation.lockToPortrait();
 }

 componentWillUnmount(){
  Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
 }

 render() {
  return(<Text>Screen 2</Text>);
 }
}
```

**Tab Navigator**

```
const AppNavigator = TabNavigator(  {
  Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
  Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
});
```

But it always portrait, which mean that its orientation always set base on orientation of last screen I add in `TabNavigator`. Any help is appreciate, thank you in advance!
**Edit 1**
I've try `StackNavigation` instead, and it work. Still don't know why it's not run with `TabNavigation`.

Comment: Try to lock the orientation in the componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount, maybe due to it is mounted can't lock it orientation.

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I've try it but it still not work, re-change immediate to last screen's orientation.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your Screen1 and Screen2 in TabNavigator are actually unmounting so they unlock the orientations?

Comment: @Unicorn Master It seem like the reason cause my error and do you have any suggestion for me to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been long time since I asked this questions, and `react-navigation` is upgrade to version 3. My solution for this problem is set orientation for tab each time it's pressed, cause tab screen isn't unmount when you click on other tab. To fix that, you can add `tabBarOnPress` to your `navigationOptions` of your screen like this

```js
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
...
class TabbarScreen1 extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    ...,
    tabBarOnPress: ({ defaultHandler }) => {
      // Orientation.lockToLandscape();
      Orientation.lockToPortrait();
      defaultHandler();
    },
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
   import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
       
   import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
   import LockedOrientationScreen from'./screens/LockedOrientationScreen';
        
   const Stack = createStackNavigator();
        
        const App = () => {
          return (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="LockedOrientation"
                  component={LockedOrientationScreen}
                  options={{
                    // Set screen here
                  }}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          );
        };
        
        export default App;
    
    
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
    
    const LockedOrientationScreen = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
      
        return () => {
          Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
        };
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>hello</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default LockedOrientationScreen;
```